# Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

When I click the checkbox I need to show an image. Right now I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
>       at (index):185
>       at dispatch (VM576 jquery.min.js:3)
>       at i (VM576 jquery.min.js:3)

Can you tell me how to fix it? I'm providing my code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/xda0kL6w/1/

```or-tag-here
if (document.getElementById('checkIDGrid').checked) {
  alert("I am checked for the grid");

  var img = $('<img />', {
    id: 'Myid',
    src: 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/pixel-perfect-web-development-flat-icons-set-website-programming-process-webpage-coding-user-interface-creating-45297890.jpg',
    alt: 'MyAlt'
  });
  img.appendTo($('<tr>'));

} else {
  alert("I am not checked for the grid");
}
```

Comment: `getElementById('checkIDGrid')` isn't returning anything, hence the error as you're calling `checked` on a null value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
const option = document.getElementById('checkIDGrid');
if ( option && option.checked) {
    ...
}
```